# R geom_bar facet_grid vertical instead of horizontal

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, facet-grid

I am trying to make the same image I have but instead of horizontal each "propuesta", I want them to be in vertical. First "Propuesta A", under it "Propuesta B", and under this last one, "Propuesta C", as if each one of them is a separate graph, but together. I have the following code and output:

```
ggplot(articles_europaoccidental_sex_count_unique_group, aes(Country, percentage, fill = Gender)) + 
+     geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
+     facet_grid(~Propuesta) + geom_text(aes(label = round(percentage, 2)), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -1)
```

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: you could use `facet_wrap` with `ncol = 1`

Comment: Try with `facet_grid(Propuesta ~ .)`. Same as `facet_grid(rows = vars(Propuesta))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Richard Telford said, with a minimum change in my code it would work.

The new code is

```
ggplot(articles_europaoccidental_sex_count_unique_group, aes(Country, percentage, fill = Gender)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  facet_wrap(~Propuesta, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

The only change was `facet_grid(~Propuesta)` to `facet_wrap(~Propuesta, ncol = 1)`